# eslint: no-implicit-coercion for if conditionals

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm using eslint with `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` in TypeScript.

Is it possible to warn the following code for using `any` type in `if` conditional?
I tried `no-implicit-coercion` rule but it did not work.

```
const foo = (a: any) => {
  if (a) { // this should be warned
    return 42;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md).

By default, it forbids `any` in conditionals, but also forbids nullable booleans, nullable strings, and nullable numbers. To only forbid `any` you could use this configuration:

```json
"rules": {
  "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": [2,  {
    "allowNullableBoolean": true,
    "allowNullableString": true,
    "allowNullableNumber": true
  }]
}
```

---

Personally, I don't recommend this though and I would keep the rule with the default settings, as it could prevent bugs like this (albeit a contrived example):

```
declare const maybeNumber: number | null
if (maybeNumber) {
  // number could actually be null, 0, or NaN!
  console.log('maybeNumber is not null!') // oops
  let thisIsNaN = 123 / maybeNumber
}
```

Also, you could also use [`@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md) to avoid `any` in your codebase entirely; use `unknown` instead.

Comment: Can I use this for boolean expected context like `[0, 1, undefined, null, 2].filter((elem: number | null | undefined) => elem /*should be warned*/)`?

Comment: @yskkin Unfortunately, that rule does not warn for those kinds of methods. If you really wanted to, you could enable [`@typescript-esilnt/explicit-function-return-type`](//github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md) and set allowHigherOrderFunctions` to `false` (it's `true` by default), which would force you to specify the return type of the filter function (`(elem: number | null | undefined): boolean`), but doesn't stop you from specifying a non-`boolean` return type.

Comment: Checking for `Array.prototype.filter` sounds like a good idea, though; maybe you should [open a feature request](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/new?assignees=&labels=package%3A+eslint-plugin%2C+triage&template=eslint-plugin-typescript.md&title=%5Brulename%5D+issue+title).